# Why *nix command line enable execution via path relative to current directory?

Tags: shell, unix

For a long time I was under impression that *NIX shells do not support running executables via path relative to current directory. Also there're a number of posts explaining why having working directory in path is a bad practice. Still it's easy to see that following example works:

```
% cat<<EOF > temp/a
? #!/bin/sh
? echo "Hello looser!"
? EOF
% chmod 750 temp/a
% temp/a
Hello looser!
```

(I tested at CentOS and OSX).

Why it works?

Upd: it's not purely academic question, I had cases when binaries run via full path and the way described above worked different way.

Upd 2: libc `execv` accepts both absolute and relative paths with no problem. Hence, support for `subpath/exe` while failing to run `exe` looks as shell feature common to bash and tcsh. There must be some logic behind it??

Answer (score 1):

You can always execute a program by specifying its relative path. There is no requirement that you would have to use an absolute path. Actually, the way you are executing your program, is quite common.

Comment: Surely not always - you can't run `exe` in current directory unless the directory is in `PATH`.

Comment: @v.v You can run `exe` in current directory without that directory in your PATH, just use `./exe`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `./` is full path with alias.

Comment: @v.v *"with alias"* ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah, `.` is an alias to current directory, so by prefixing path with `./` you make it absolute.

Comment: @v.v No. `./` is not an absolute path. It's a relative path.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's scholastic argument. It's relative with respect to current directory but is absolute from the point of syntax - `./` is an explicit pointer to current directory. As opposite, path with no prefix at all is "truly" relative as prefixing with current directory is implicitly assumed. Maybe I'd rather use "explicit/implicit" wording..

Comment: @v.v No. An absolute pathname is defined by POSIX to be a pathname that starts with a single `/`. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you very much for reminding the definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you write `command` with no `/` then the shell searches `$PATH` for the command.

If you write `dir/command` with a relative directory, there's a `/` and the shell **does not search `$PATH`**. It interprets it relative to the current directory. `dir/command` always resolves to `./dir/command`.

Putting `.` in the `$PATH` is dangerous because you may type `command` intend ing to run `/usr/bin/command` but actually get `./command` if it exists in the current directory. Indeed, it's not just `.` that's dangerous: any relative path is dangerous. **`$PATH` should only ever contain absolute paths.**

---

> So, you're saying that relative paths shall be implicitly prefixed with current directory, with exceptional case when relative path is empty that shall be treated as direction to search in `$PATH`?

Yes, you could say that. But I prefer to reframe it. A better way to think of it is to understand what the *shell* is doing versus what the *kernel* is doing.

Interpreting relative paths is handled implicitly by the kernel. When the shell performs a system call like [`execve("dir/command", ...)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) to execute a program the kernel knows the parent process's current directory and resolves `dir/command` relative to it. The shell does not have to first convert the path into an absolute one. The kernel can handle both absolute and relative paths.

The kernel knows nothing about `$PATH`, though. That's a shell construct. Keep in mind that the shell is a higher level piece of software. The shell decides that if you type a simple command name without a `/` in it, it will not simply pass that command to the kernel. If it did, typing `cat` would simply execute `./cat`. Nobody wants that.

Instead, the shell decides that the lack of a `/` means it will search for the command in the `$PATH`. It'll search `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `$HOME/bin`, etc. If you listed `.` in the `$PATH` then it would also search the current directory—don't do that! You *don't* want it to run `./cat`. No sir.

If the shell finds an executable in the `$PATH` then it converts it to an absolute path name and passes that to the kernel. The kernel sees `execve("/usr/bin/cat", ...)`.

---

> If so and you know it from some formal specification, I'd appreciate the reference. I do need to know precisely.

See the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If the command name contains no slashes, the shell attempts to locate it. …
>
> If the name … contains no slashes, bash searches each element of the `PATH` for a directory containing an executable file by that name. …
>
> If the search is successful, or if the command name contains one or more slashes, the shell executes the named program ….

Comment: If you type `exe` then per my first paragraph the shell searches `$PATH`. It'll only search the current directory if `$PATH` contains `.`. Which is exactly why it shouldn't!

Comment: I've added a citation from the Bash manual. It's all about the presence or absence of a slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

This as nothing to do with execution. It is due to the fact that you can name a file with an absolute or a relative name, and that executables are just ordinary files.

> Why is it dangerous? (`.`in `PATH`)

Think about a script that calls a command like `cat foo`, if you have `.` in the path then it could be possible to create a command `cat` in the same directory that would be executed in place of the original one.

Comment: I know why `.` in `PATH` is bad practise. What I miss is why `temp/a` works while `a` (in current directory) doesn't - is there any clear policy when relative path can be used to call binary? _"Whenever but not in current dir"_ seems pretty weird to me.

Comment: You may have a "global" script that calls subscripts in sub-directories, each one doing a specific job inside its own directory. This is pretty common.

Comment: yes, I might :) But the question is different: what's the precise specification of calling executables via relative path.

Comment: not correct: if you have executable `exe` in current directory you can't call it as just `exe`.